# Is there a general formula for counting the number of constraints the family of rotation matrices provide?

Tags: combinatorics, rotations

In 2D case, the rotation matrices are specified with $R$, conditioned on $R^TR = 1$. This condition is equivalent to say: 
$$ q_i q_j =\begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\ne j \end{cases},$$
which contributes **3** constraints for different $(i, j)$ pairs: $(1, 1) \text{ and } (1, 2) \text{ and } (2, 2)$.

As in 3D case, the rotation matrices with the same form provide **6** constraints for different $(i, j)$ pairs.

My question is:

For rotation matrices manipulated in **n-dimensional**, is there a general formula for counting the number of constraints they provide? Perhaps using combinatorics, i.e. **k-permutations** and **combinations** 
$$\binom{n}k$$

Comment: Use `\begin{cases}\end{cases}` and `\binom{n}k`

Comment: What are the $q_j$s?

Comment: I don't understand what's the question, but the dimension of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ i.e. the space of matrices of the form $R^t R =I$ is $n(n-1)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is your friend.

Comment: This formula is right! However, can you show me the derivation? I mean,  how to count the number of different $(i, j)$ pairs **from combinatorics**? i.e. k-permutations and combinations.

Comment: This is just $\binom{n}{2}$ picking a subset of $2$ elements in a set of $n$ elements.